# unix remove duplicate block of lines, keep first

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, duplicates

This is an extract from the jobs in my TWS database,  my blocks start with:

```
/^ES2BVE1011 # EM5341CAI000 (jobname)
```

and end with:

```
/^ RECOVERY (can be STOP ou CONTINUE)
```

I have duplicate blocks, I would like to keep only the first one to minimize the time loading, only if the entire block has all same lines, because it can be the same jobname, but others lines in the block can has differences:

```
ES2BVE1011 # EM5341CAI000  
 SCRIPTNAME "/s2ipgm/scripts/current/em5341cai000.sh -scai -eexp"  
 STREAMLOGON us2icai  
 DESCRIPTION "balance sheet errors"  
 UNIX TASKTYPE  
 SUCCOUTPUTCOND CONDSUCC "(RC = 0)"  
 RECOVERY STOP  
ES2BVE1011 # ED5237CAI001  
 SCRIPTNAME "/s2ipgm/scripts/current/ed5237com001.sh -scai -eexp"  
 STREAMLOGON us2icai  
 DESCRIPTION "bb / ir account list"  
 UNIX TASKTYPE  
 SUCCOUTPUTCOND CONDSUCC "(RC = 0)"  
 RECOVERY STOP  
ES2BVE1011 # CA4305CAI000  
 SCRIPTNAME "/s2ipgm/scripts/current/ea4305com000.sh -scai -ecpt"  
 STREAMLOGON us2icai  
 DESCRIPTION "list op. Fid."  
 UNIX TASKTYPE  
 SUCCOUTPUTCOND CONDSUCC "(RC = 0)"  
 RECOVERY STOP  
ES2BVE1011 # CM4622CAI000  
 SCRIPTNAME "/s2ipgm/scripts/current/em4622com000.sh -scai -ecpt"  
 STREAMLOGON us2icai  
 DESCRIPTION "list of debits covered / not c"  
 UNIX TASKTYPE  
 SUCCOUTPUTCOND CONDSUCC "(RC = 0)"  
 RECOVERY STOP  
ES2BVE1011 # ED5237CAI001  
 SCRIPTNAME "/s2ipgm/scripts/current/ed5237com001.sh -scai -eexp"  
 STREAMLOGON us2icai  
 DESCRIPTION "bb / ir account list"  
 UNIX TASKTYPE  
 SUCCOUTPUTCOND CONDSUCC "(RC = 0)"  
 RECOVERY STOP  
ES2BVE1011 # CJ5326CAI000  
 SCRIPTNAME "/s2ipgm/scripts/current/ej5326cai000.sh -scai -ecpt"  
 STREAMLOGON us2icai  
 DESCRIPTION "daily report"  
 UNIX TASKTYPE  
 SUCCOUTPUTCOND CONDSUCC "(RC = 0)"  
 RECOVERY STOP  
ES2BVE1011 # CA4305CAI000  
 SCRIPTNAME "/s2ipgm/scripts/current/ea4305com000.sh -scai -ecpt"  
 STREAMLOGON us2icai  
 DESCRIPTION "list op. Fid."  
 UNIX TASKTYPE  
 SUCCOUTPUTCOND CONDSUCC "(RC = 0)"  
 RECOVERY STOP  
ES2BVE1011 # ED5237CAI001  
 SCRIPTNAME "/usr/bin/true"  
 STREAMLOGON us2ipgm  
 DESCRIPTION "bb / ir account list"  
 UNIX TASKTYPE  
 SUCCOUTPUTCOND CONDSUCC "(RC = 0)"  
 RECOVERY STOP
```

Comment: please update your question with the expected output given the sample set of input; also, what coding/scripting have you tried so far?

Answer (score 6):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ block = block $0 ORS }
/^ RECOVERY/ {
    if ( !seen[block]++ ) {
        printf "%s", block
    }
    block = ""
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
ES2BVE1011 # EM5341CAI000
 SCRIPTNAME "/s2ipgm/scripts/current/em5341cai000.sh -scai -eexp"
 STREAMLOGON us2icai
 DESCRIPTION "balance sheet errors"
 UNIX TASKTYPE
 SUCCOUTPUTCOND CONDSUCC "(RC = 0)"
 RECOVERY STOP
ES2BVE1011 # ED5237CAI001
 SCRIPTNAME "/s2ipgm/scripts/current/ed5237com001.sh -scai -eexp"
 STREAMLOGON us2icai
 DESCRIPTION "bb / ir account list"
 UNIX TASKTYPE
 SUCCOUTPUTCOND CONDSUCC "(RC = 0)"
 RECOVERY STOP
ES2BVE1011 # CA4305CAI000
 SCRIPTNAME "/s2ipgm/scripts/current/ea4305com000.sh -scai -ecpt"
 STREAMLOGON us2icai
 DESCRIPTION "list op. Fid."
 UNIX TASKTYPE
 SUCCOUTPUTCOND CONDSUCC "(RC = 0)"
 RECOVERY STOP
ES2BVE1011 # CM4622CAI000
 SCRIPTNAME "/s2ipgm/scripts/current/em4622com000.sh -scai -ecpt"
 STREAMLOGON us2icai
 DESCRIPTION "list of debits covered / not c"
 UNIX TASKTYPE
 SUCCOUTPUTCOND CONDSUCC "(RC = 0)"
 RECOVERY STOP
ES2BVE1011 # CJ5326CAI000
 SCRIPTNAME "/s2ipgm/scripts/current/ej5326cai000.sh -scai -ecpt"
 STREAMLOGON us2icai
 DESCRIPTION "daily report"
 UNIX TASKTYPE
 SUCCOUTPUTCOND CONDSUCC "(RC = 0)"
 RECOVERY STOP
ES2BVE1011 # ED5237CAI001
 SCRIPTNAME "/usr/bin/true"
 STREAMLOGON us2ipgm
 DESCRIPTION "bb / ir account list"
 UNIX TASKTYPE
 SUCCOUTPUTCOND CONDSUCC "(RC = 0)"
 RECOVERY STOP
```

Comment: I noticed that we let records start with the "RECOVERY" row this way, and this can print a record twice, especially the first one, or omit the "RECOVERY" row from the last one. Moving the second action `{ block = block $0 ORS }` at the beginning seems to resolve both issues.

Comment: @thanasisp Yeah, that's the fix, thanks, I updated my answer now. That's one of the reasons I should know to only answer questions that include expected output - so there's something to diff a tool output against to see if it worked rather than having to eyeball it and essentially guess if it's correct or not. Lesson re-learned for me!

Comment: @thanasisp it's already answered, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62196867/1745001