# awk: negative exponential is not correctly interpreted

Tags: shell, if-statement, unix, awk, exponential

I have this table:

```
a   0
b   0
c   1.6149e-315
d   5.2587e-265
e   8.2045e-227
f   8.2045e-227
```

If I type

```
$awk '($2<1){print}' my_file.txt
```

it returns

```
a   0
b   0
d   5.2587e-265
e   8.2045e-227
f   8.2045e-227
```

but it considers the value in the third row, 1.6149e-315, to be larger than 1:

```
$awk '($2>1){print}' my_file.txt 
c   1.6149e-315
```

Which is the reason for this behaviour? Is a negative exponential <1e-300 too small so it removes the "e-" part? It looks so, since

```
$awk '($2>1.6149){print}' my_file.txt 
c   1.6149e-315
```

but if I run

```
$ awk '($2>1.615){print}' my_file.txt
```

nothing is output.

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your awk like this:

```
awk '($2+0) < 1' file
```

This will output:

```
a   0
b   0
c   1.6149e-315
d   5.2587e-265
e   8.2045e-227
f   8.2045e-227
```

`$2+0` converts `$2` into a numeric value.

btw on `GNU Awk 5.0.1`, I get correct output even without this trick.

Answer (score -1):

Reproduced the OP's issue with `GNU Awk 4.2.1`.

---

First of all, `$NF+0` seems not to solve this issue, as we can see in this example:

```
> cat file
a   0
b   0
c   1.6149e-315
d   5.2587e-265
e   8.2045e-227
f   8.2045e-227

> awk '$2+0>0' file
d   5.2587e-265
e   8.2045e-227
f   8.2045e-227
```

The third number of the sample input is not printed again, while it should be greater than zero.

And here we see only zeros for the third number.

```
awk '{printf "%.320f\n",$2+0}' file
```

The above are indicating that `e^-315` is not being represented in an expected way.

---

It seems like you have exceeded the limit which is `-308` for double-precision floating point. Around `e^-308` is the minimum positive non zero value to be represented.

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computer-Arithmetic

---

Furthermore, if your gnu awk is compiled with MPFR support, you can have multiple precision numbers, using the -M option, which seems the only way to represent a positive number less that `10^-308`

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/MPFR-features.html

---

One last argument, a simple test:

```
> cat file
a   1.1e-312
b   1.1e-311
c   1.1e-310
d   1.1e-309
e   1.1e-308
f   1.1e-307
g   1.1e-306
h   1.1e-305
> awk '$2+0>0' file
f   1.1e-307
g   1.1e-306
h   1.1e-305
```

exponents less than `-308` are not treated as expected.

```
> awk '{print($2+0)}' file
0
0
0
0
0
1.1e-307
1.1e-306
1.1e-305
```

and this is the proof, that `$NF+0` forces to zero and not to the expontential number, any numbers beyond `^-308` cannot be represented because of that limit, which exists for awk instances with double-precision and no support for multi-precision.

Comment: I didn't downvote. I could reproduce the issue on gawk 4.1.4 but not gawk 5.0.1 nor OSX/BSD awk version 20070501. Maybe it was just a gawk bug that got fixed otherwise why would the problem not occur in other awks, including more recent versions of gawk?

Comment: I am sure you didn't! as I have seen your way and your posts around here. This is why I asked for reviewing this issue the other day. Also nevermind if anyone downvoted, no problem. I use `GNU Awk 4.2.1` without multiple precision support, if I execute `awk -M` I get `awk: warning: -M ignored: MPFR/GMP support not compiled in`. Probably awk 5 has multiple precision support by default and you cannot reproduce the issue. You can see `awk -M` or just `awk --version` for if they say anything about MPFR support for your installations. Thank you.

Comment: GNU awk shows `GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0)` but I thought you had to specify `-M` when you call gawk for it to use MPFR so it didn't break existing code that didn't use it. The gawk manual certainly seems to be saying that in https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#MPFR-features (`if it was compiled to do so, and the -M command-line option is supplied, gawk uses the GNU MPFR and GNU MP (GMP) libraries...`). OSX/BSD awk doesn't mention MPFR - not sure that was even a possibility in 2007 when this version was released.

Comment: Yes, it seems true that it should be enabled only with `-M`. But if you try my last example, `print($2+0)`, i guess it handles numbers less than `^-308`.

Comment: Both gawk 5.0.1 (with or without --posix or --tradtitional flags) and OSX/BSD awk 20070501 print the values from $2 as-is. gawk 4.1.4 produces the same output you show with 0s for the first 5 rows.

Comment: Also, I tried `awk 'END {print PREC}' file` and I get `53`, the default, says here https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Setting-precision.html#table_002dpredefined_002dprecision_002dstrings

Comment: @EdMorton I see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Setting-precision.html) how you set (downgrade from multiple to double in your case) PREC to reproduce this issue. You can test: `awk '{print $1+0, $2+0}' <<< "1e-306 1e-310"` and `awk 'BEGIN{PREC="double"} {print $1+0, $2+0}' <<< "1e-306 1e-310"`. For `"double"`, `-308` is the limit and prints zero.