# Delete rows of a CSV file based off a column value on command line

Tags: csv, awk, command-line

I have a large file that I cannot open on my computer. I am trying to delete rows of information that are unneeded.
My file looks like this:

```
NODE,107983_gene,382,666,-,cd10161,8,49,9.0E-100,49.4,0.52,domain
NODE,107985_gene,24,659,-,PF09699.9,108,148,6.3E-500,22.5,0.8571428571428571,domain
NODE,33693_gene,213,1433,-,PF01966.21,92,230,9.0E-10,38.7,0.9344262295081968,domain
NODE,33693_gene,213,1433,-,PRK04926,39,133,1.0E-8,54.5,0.19,domain
NODE,33693_gene,213,1433,-,cd00077,88,238,4.0E-6,44.3,0.86,domain
NODE,33693_gene,213,1433,-,smart00471,88,139,9.0E-7,41.9,0.42,domain
NODE,33694_gene,1430,1912,-,cd16326,67,135,4.0E-50,39.5,0.38,domain
```

I am trying to remove all lines that have an evalue more than 1.0E-10. This information in located in column 9. I have tried on command line:

```
awk '$9 >=1E-10' file name > outputfile
```

This has given me a smaller file but the evalues are all over the place and are not actually removing anything above 1E-10. I want small E-values only.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I assume when you say you can't open it you mean that whatever editor you use can't display it, not that you really can't open it, is that right? [edit] your question to show the expected output given the sample input you posted and make sure to point out which line(s) from your input your existing script fails for. In your code you are printing lines where $9 is greater than or equal to a value but it sounds like you actually want to print the lines that are less than that value - maybe you just have the sign going the wrong way and should be using `<` instead of `>=`?

Comment: I can't open the file because it is so large that it will crash my computer.

Comment: I assume that crashed computer is why it took over 3 months to respond :-). You still didn''t say what tool you're trying to open the file with as that tool is what is crashing your computer, not the size of the file itself. You might want to ask a new question if you have one, I doubt if anyone will be looking at this one after all this time has passed.

Answer (score 2):

almost there, you need to specify the field delimiter

```
$ awk -F, '$9<1E-10' file > small.values
```

Comment: I leave a note (as I see `E-500` in the sample file) For older awk versions, without MPFR support, without multiple presicion, but only double precision, there is a limitation, around `E-308` is the minimum positive number represented and anything smaller is considered zero. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62196591/awk-negative-exponential-is-not-correctly-interpreted/62197106#62197106

Comment: @thanasisp thanks for the note.  I highly suspect any meaningful real life `E-500` values.  Regardless here it will resolve in the right bucket.